# Multiple Stored Procs ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I am creating a page that uses multiple stored procedures to populate drop down lists. The stored procedures have parameters that are the selection of the previous drop down list (ie they need to be run in order). What would be the best way to implement this functionality? I am using ASP MVC and am having a difficult time passing the results to a viewmodel to render again.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you are trying to have cascading dropdowns.
and you are binding your dropdown using Stored Procedures..right??

Here is an example: I have two drop downs. School and Course. When you change the selected value in school, the course dropdown will change its value.

This is controller:

```
 public ActionResult SchoolList(int id)
    {
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> schools = new Util().GetSchoolSelectList(id);
        if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            return Json(schools, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        return View(schools);
    }

    public ActionResult CourseList(int id)
    {
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> courses = new Util().GetCourseSelectList(id);
        if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            return Json(courses, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        return View(courses);
    }
```

And this is jquery:

```
$("#Schools").change(function () {
        $.getJSON("/Account/CourseList/" + $("#Schools").val(), function (data) {
            var items = "<option>Select your Course</option>";
            $.each(data, function (i, course) {
                items += "<option value='" + course.Value + "'>" + course.Text + "</option>";
            });
            $("#Courses").html(items);
        });
    });
```

And this is HTML:

```
<select id="Schools" name="UserSchool"></select> 

<select id="Courses" name="UserCourse"></select>
```